# unable to compile mysql source

Tags: c++, mysql

Am trying to compile mysql client library source

```
source paclage\client\mysql.cc
```

i used gcc and g++ both

```
g++ -o mysql.cc mysql.cc
```

so whenever i compile it always gives error

```
In file included from mysql.cc:33:0:
client_priv.h:20:23: fatal error: my_global.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

although my_global.h already exists , i moved it to the root folder of mysql.cc but same error , i did everything with it , but same error that library not found , i copied code of my_global.h and paste it in client_priv.h  after that when i compile it says other libraries missing which were listed in client_priv.h ........ so help its quite confusing

Comment: From where did you download the source?

Comment: http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/mysql-5.1/mysql-5.1.67.tar.gz

Comment: You need to read up on package compilation. You really can't just use gcc to compile random packages. That's what make and its ilk are for.

Comment: OK. There are a lot of files in that archive, what gave you the impression that they were not needed and `g++ -o mysql.cc mysql.cc` would be all you needed? Also `-o mysql.cc` is probably not the best plan.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow [official guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/source-installation.html)

Running gcc is not enough because there are lot of environment settings to be set, eg LIB paths, include paths etc.

They are using CMake to prepare build for you.

UPDATE:

If you want to compile program which will use mysql client library follow this [guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/building-clients.html).

Comment: oh crap thats so long :D  anybody have static libs (.a) of mysql i was trying to get static libs so that i have not to use   libmysql.dll with my application .....

Comment: @darkworks : static libs are dependent of linker version of used tools chain and architecture.What you are trying to achieve? Maybe there is very simple solution ;)